# Call method before another

Tags: php

I have bunch of methods in which i need to test whether remote server has been reached or not and if not, reach it.

My first idea was __call magic method, but the method is called **only when real method** (with the original name) **is not presented**.

```
<?php
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    $needsExecution = array(
        'getBody', 'getHeader', 'getHeaders', 'getRawOutput',
        'getStatusCode', 'getFullHttp'
    );

    if ( in_array( $name, $needsExecution ) ) {
        if ( !$this->hasBeenExecuted() ) {
            $this->execute();
        }
    }
}

public function getBody() {
    return $this->responseBody;
}


public function getHeaders() {
    return $this->responseHeaders;
}

?>
```

Do I really need to have bunch of if's in each method or there's a way how to do that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing up your code like this:

```
<?php
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    $needsExecution = array(
        'getBody', 'getHeader', 'getHeaders', 'getRawOutput',
        'getStatusCode', 'getFullHttp'
    );

    if ( in_array( $name, $needsExecution ) ) {
        if ( !$this->hasBeenExecuted() ) {
            $this->execute();
        } 
        return $this->{'_' . $name}();
        //return call_user_func(array($this, '_' . $name));
    }
}

protected function _getBody() {
    return $this->responseBody;
}


protected function _getHeaders() {
    return $this->responseHeaders;
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, it's legal: `$this->{'_'.$funtionName}()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing...but if you want to intercept every method call.

```
class ObjectProxy {
    protected $obj;
    function __construct($obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }
    function __call($methodName, $arguments) {
        //do stuff
        return call_user_func_array($methodName, $this->obj, $arguments);
    }
}

$proxied = new ObjectProxy(new OrigionalType());
$proxied->getBody();
```

You probably want to implement more of the magic methods to make it work for more than instance method calls, but you get the point. It's not a solution for all situations, but can be handy at times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are overcomplicating this. (Assuming I understood your question.)

Why not just have the function that talks to the remote server set a flag when it is done?

Why do you need to check each stage of the connection? And why are they separate stages anyway? Don't they all work together in a specific order, and never from any other code? There isn't any reason to make them individual functions. (Unless there is more to your code that I don't know about.)